# How it's possible to have same variable and function name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We usually use `React.memo` as follow

```js
const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
});
```

We have a `MyComponent` function and a `MyComponent` variable in the same scope, Why the syntax is correct and we have no runtime error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'MyComponent' has already been declared`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a function declaration (you don't have one, this is for the sake of comparison):

```
function example() {
    ...
}
```

The identifier `example` does **two** distinct things.

1. It sets the function name to `example`
2. It creates a variable named `example` and assigns the function to it

It is important to distinguish between the name of a function and any variables that reference it.

You could go on to do:

```
const foo = example;
```

So now you have a function **named** `example` and two variables (`foo` and `example`) which can be used to access it.

---

The syntax you have in the question is a function **expression** not a function **declaration**.

One of the differences between function expressions and declarations is that the identifier **only** names the function. It does not create a variable of the same name. (Another difference is that the identifier for expressions is optional, you have a named function expression).

Since it doesn't create a variable, there is no conflict with `const MyComponent`.